# content from a website in a text file

Tags: c#, file, web

My aim is to get content from a website (for instance a league table from a sports website) and put it in a .txt file so that I can code with a local file.

I have tried multiple lines of code and others examples such as:

```
// prepare the web page we will be asking for
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
// prepare the web page we will be asking for
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // we will read data via the response stream
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
            if (count != 0)
        {
        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

        // continue building the string
        sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
    }
```

My issue is when trying this, is that the words request and response are underlined in read and all the tokens are invalid.
Is there a better method to get content from a website to a .txt file or is there a way to fix the code supplied?

Thanks

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFile()` downloads and saves in a single call.

Comment: Do I just add that to the bottom of what I currently have or is that the only line I need?

Comment: Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to fix the code supplied?

The code you submitted works for me, make sure you have the proper name spaces defined.
In this case : `using System.Net;`

Or might it be that the duplicate creation of the variable request isn't a typo?
If so remove one of the request variables.

> Is there a better method to get content from a website to a .txt file

Since you're reading all the content from the site anyway there isn't really a need for the while loop. Instead you can use the ReadToEnd method supplied by the StreamReader.

```
string siteContent = "";    
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream)) {
   siteContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Also be sure to dispose of the WebResponse, other than that your code should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Will try this a post if anything changes either today or tomorrow. Thanks again guys!

Comment: Oh btw - the code still is red underlined in the places stated. Were you using visual studio 2015 or anything else?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015. It would be helpful if you could give us the error message it is given you by hovering over the red underline text.

Comment: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MainPage.request'

Comment: yeah. It is in its subroutine.

Comment: If you could update your question with more code (entire class) I could help you out. With the current information I can't find a solution.